# Is the I3 wm available on PureOS?

Tags: i3, pureos

Searching the PureOS repo on https://software.pureos.net/categories didn't show any results for i3 i3wm or sway. It's debian so I assume it's possible if I add a repo but I'd prefer to use official.

Answer (score 1):

The PureOS website is a bit confusing. The search on https://software.pureos.net/categories will not found i3 or sway, the "Find a package" search on https://software.pureos.net/suites will:

- https://software.pureos.net/package/bin/byzantium/sway
- https://software.pureos.net/package/bin/amber/i3

Answer (score 1):

On the site which you link there are [i3](https://software.pureos.net/package/bin/amber/i3), [i3-wm](https://software.pureos.net/package/bin/amber/i3-wm), and [sway](https://software.pureos.net/package/bin/byzantium/sway). The last one starts with PureOS "byzantium" while the rest are also available in "amber".

---

You can install `i3` on PureOS the same way as on Debian:

```
sudo apt install i3
```

Under PureOS "amber", this will install i3-wm with dependencies, such as i3status, i3lock, suckless-tools. After installing, logout, choose i3 session under the gear ⚙ menu, and login.